# replace string php, but every change make a new variabel

Tags: php

i have

```
$str ="GOODDAY"
```

and i need to replace `O` with `U` , but not change ALL `O` characters.

For example

```
$str1 ="GUODDAY" ; 
$str2 ="GOUDDAY" ; 
$str3 ="GUUDDAY" ;
```

i used str_replace but only get $str3 , any idea?

Comment: Has this practical applications? Are you aware of arrays? Can you formulate the successive replacement behaviour more explicitly?

Comment: Show what you tried...it's much easier to help if we see precisely what you were doing.

Comment: sorry  it first post but thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to print the string as many times as the occurrences of O, and replace O once each time, according to the iteration number, and finally print the string with all O replaced. This will do it:

```
$str = "GOODDAY";
$find = "O";
$replaceWith = "U";
$lastPos = 0;

while (($lastPos = strpos($str, $find, $lastPos)) !== false) {
    echo substr_replace($str, $replaceWith, $lastPos, 1) . "\n";
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($find);
}

echo str_replace($find, $replaceWith, $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/ddg73

Comment: Ok, I understand, you want ALL the possibilities, not just 1 randomly :) So this is the good answer, but question was unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this :

```php
$str ="GOODDAY";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    if ($str[$i] === 'O' && rand(0, 1) === 1) {
        $str[$i] = 'U';
    }
}

echo $str;
```

**Edit :**
If you want at least 1 U with same chances for each possibility:

```php
do {
    $str ="GOODDAY";
    $good = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i] === 'O' && rand(0, 1) === 1) {
            $str[$i] = 'U';
            $good = true;
        }
    }
} while (false === $good);

echo $str;
```

Comment: still GOODDAY  , if echo in for , has 6 string and imposiblle to compare with $str first,but thank

Comment: Why do you randomly decide to replace the character?

Comment: Because what I understand from the question is that he wants to replace at least 1 "O", and this randomly.